# Grammar Xtext (Model,view,controller)

Tags: eclipse, model-view-controller, grammar, xtext

Good evening to all ,
I always try to create a grammar Dsl (xtext).
My grammar must contain a model part, a view part and a controller part
I already asked a question when I tried to create the view part of my grammar xtext.

Now I have to create the controller part, it must contain events like onClick buttons and also it must define the relations between the view and the database (business part or the model) But I found nothing in this context as examples or tutorials.
Thanks for helping me .

Comment: Can you please elaborate what your problem is. Did you make familiar with concepts like cross references in Xtext. Did you do the tutorial.

Comment: And once again. The what is the interesting part. And the what in your part is MVC . And you have to think about how MVC can be expressed in a model.

Comment: I have not yet seen this tutorial,I'll see it now .Mvc is the what yes
But how to realize the grammar In model Mvc?What I know is that I must have 3 parts :1- the model in which I will put my side database .                                                                                                   2- the view.  3- Controller: and I know that here I have to put and establish the relation between my database and my view (the events ..) in principle .But the syntax to follow in this 3rd part is not clear for me.

Comment: Ähhhm it's your job to propose the syntax isn't it. So what about proposing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MVC: Model | View | Controller;
...
Controller: "controller" name=ID 'for' view=[View] "{"
    models+=ModelReference*
    actions+=Action*
    bindings+=Binding*
"}";
ModelReference: "model" name=ID ":" type=[Entity]
Action: "action" name=ID "on" button=[Button] //todo implement scoping
        "{" ..... "}"
Binding: "bind" model=[ModelReference] "." field=[Field] //todo implement scoping
"to" textField=[TextField] //todo implement scoping
```